# TS Cannot find name 'foo.ts' in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2022

Typescript compiler cannot 'see' files in the same directory in Visual Studio 2022. Each reference to a class in a different file gives a version of the following error:

`Error  TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'foo'.`

Project properties are set as per the below:

[image]

I also have `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` nuget package installed (v4.8.3).

Not really sure where to go with this - it was working until I restarted VS for some other reason, but now on reload I get this error. If I copy all the classes into one ts script, the compiler is happy and I can run the code fine.

Comment: Same here, it works in Visual Studio 2019, so I have changed the IDE until I found a solution

Comment: Have you perhaps found a solution (other than VS2019)?

Comment: Nothing so far - meant to be picking it back up next week so it will come to a head then!